# An elongated copy query in MS Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-migration

So, I learnt the joys(/s) of `INNER JOIN` today. Now I need to copy select records from certain specific columns into my main column. Once again, I'll be using the following format:

*Please bear in mind that I'm working with 300,000 records. Copy/pasting one by one is not practical.*

**Tables:**
MainTab
CritTab

**Key column:**
MainTab:- LINK
CritTab:- FORNLINK

**Columns to be copied**
CritTab.DATE
CritTab.CODE

**Criteria**
`WHERE CritTab.[CODE] = <This kinda code> OR <This other code>
AND CritTab.[FORNLINK] = MainTab.[LINK]`

So, to clarify: I need to copy specific columns from CritTab to MainTab. As not every record in MainTab will have a corresponding CritTab entry, I cannot simply copy and paste the entire column, as some records won't match up.

Is it possible to do this with a query in Access?

Comment: Looks like two queries to me. One to update, one to add records.

Comment: @Fionnuala I'm not sure what you mean. Why do I need to add records? I already have the required fields in the main table, if that's what you mean

Comment: It looks like you would like to execute an `Update` query. Have a look at [this short techonthnet article](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/update2.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you need the columns added or not, but if you do run these first. I am changing the column name because you should never use [keywords](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx) as a column, table or variable name.

```
ALTER TABLE MainTab ADD COLUMN DATENAME DATETIME
ALTER TABLE MainTab ADD COLUMN CODENAME (WHATEVER DATA TYPE IT IS IN CritTab)
```

I am moving the `JOIN` operator from the where clause to the `FROM` clause. This usually makes it easier to understand how the data is being built and clutters the WHERE a bit less in my opinion. Note: I am doing the same sort of syntax as the article Mike posted in the comments.

```
UPDATE MainTab INNER JOIN CritTab ON CritTab.[FORNLINK] = MainTab.[LINK]
SET MainTab.DATENAME = CritTab.[Date], MainTab.CODENAME = CritTab.[CODE] 
WHERE CritTab.[CODE] = <This kinda code> OR CritTab.[CODE] = <This other code>
```

Comment: Really appreciate the help, but this appears to be updating `CritTab`, not `MainTab`. In addition, the update command is wiping entries in `CritTab`, so that they match `MainTab`. Any ideas?

Comment: Your `OR` statement doesn't seem right. It should be `CritTab.Code = "Compcert" OR  CritTab.Code = "RegCert"`. The second part of the `OR` statement always evaluates to `TRUE` since it is not comparing anything against anything, and ignores the `CritTab.Code = 'Compcert'` completely, selecting everything. This was a mistake in my example, and I will fix it to reflect that.

Comment: Nope, still writes to CritTab.

Comment: I copied the above query, and setup two tables to reflect the data structure as far as I know it. The query being `UPDATE MainTab INNER JOIN CritTab ON CritTab.[FORNLINK] = MainTab.[LINK]
SET MainTab.DATECode = CritTab.[Date] 
WHERE CritTab.[CODE] = '1' OR CritTab.[CODE] = '2'`. Are you certain that you have the `SET MainTab.ComCode=CritTab.Code`, because it ran as expected?

Comment: Not sure. I ended up doing something similar, like so: `UPDATE CritTab INNER JOIN MainTab ON CritTab.FORNLINK = MainTab.LINK SET MainTab.COMCODE = [CritTab]![CODE]
WHERE (((MainTab.COMCODE)="This Kinda Value"));`

Comment: Sorry you ran into that issue, good job on finding a solution!